# CSS: Fixing overflow issue with div and fixing background image

Tags: css, html, web

I'm in the process of making a website and I'm terrible at CSS so I'm running into a few issues that I'm not sure how to deal with.

This is the website site I'm working on here:
http://www2.hawaii.edu/~akinsey/sandbox/broken/

I'm having two main issues. The first is that when the content flows past the bottom of the page it messes up the background on the content div. How can I make it so when the text overflows the page, the tiling of the content div doesn't stop (You can see what I'm talking about if you scroll to the bottom of the link above). I'm pretty sure this is happening because I'm using a fixed position for the main div wrapper. The reason I did this was so the content div would extend all the way to the bottom. Without the fixed position it was stretching all the way to the bottom, but it caused the page to have a vertical scroll bar even though there was no content on the page.

The second issue I'm having is with the Hawaiian Pattern background image on the right. I wasn't too sure how to accomplish this: I want the image to be exactly where it is now, but currently when you scroll so does that particular background image. Essentially I want it attached to the right side of all the page content (like it is now), and to stay in that position even when you re-size the page or scroll.

Basically I want the webpage to look like this version:
http://www2.hawaii.edu/~akinsey/sandbox/index2.html

But with a working scroll bar that doesn't mess up all of the background images.

Here is my current css:

```
html { text-align: center; margin:0; padding:0; height:100%; }
body { text-align: center; margin:0; padding:0; height:100%; background-image:url('../image/bg.gif'); background-repeat:repeat-x; }
#wrapper { height:100%; width:100%; margin:0 auto; position: fixed; }
#innerwrapper { margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; width:975px; height:100%; background-image: url("../image/hawaiianpattern.gif"); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position: right top; }
#header { margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; width:810px; background-image:url('../image/header1.png'); height:100px; }
#navbar { margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; width:800px; height:35px; background-image: url('../image/navbg.gif'); background-repeat:repeat-x; }
#content { margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; width:804px; height:100%; background-image: url('../image/contentbg.gif'); background-repeat:repeat-y; }
#contentholder { padding-top:10px; text-align:left; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; width:90%; height:100%; }
```

And here is the accompanying html:

```
<!-- Site Wrapper -->
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="innerwrapper">
    <!-- Header -->
    <div id="header"></div>

    <!-- Navigation Bar -->
    <div id="navbar">
        <ul class="lavaLampNoImage" id="1">
            <li id="l1" class="current"><a id="n1" class="navlink" style="color:black" href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li id="l2" ><a id="n2" class="navlink" href="#">About</a></li>
            <li id="l3" ><a id="n3" class="navlink" href="#">Forum</a></li>
            <li id="l4" ><a id="n4" class="navlink" href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <!-- Content -->
    <div id="content">
    <div id="contentholder">
        <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut a risus urna, ut consequat nibh. In ut pharetra nisl. Etiam vitae ante sed sem fermentum lobortis. Cras ac varius magna. Nunc fringilla dolor id diam lobortis dapibus. Etiam lobortis, elit vitae lobortis sagittis, lacus orci cursus ligula, ut suscipit libero est eu odio. Mauris tellus est, tristique id convallis tincidunt, placerat at enim. Sed augue ante, molestie a tempus a, vehicula nec ligula. Etiam rhoncus, est eget ultrices pulvinar, ipsum enim congue velit, quis lobortis neque lacus non neque. Sed accumsan felis id neque cursus lacinia. Donec vitae leo ut ante aliquam hendrerit. Morbi commodo, lacus at pretium tristique, justo ante fermentum metus, eget condimentum augue turpis quis urna. Fusce eu erat eget dolor consequat vehicula. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
        </p>
        <p>
        Fusce vestibulum vestibulum tortor, sit amet molestie sem euismod eget. Nullam ornare felis ut urna consectetur ut vestibulum risus lacinia. Etiam ligula libero, pharetra sit amet eleifend vel, tincidunt pulvinar magna. Nullam lacinia auctor sollicitudin. Praesent et leo dolor. Etiam lacinia, nisi at aliquet dignissim, tellus ante aliquet arcu, tincidunt facilisis magna nibh cursus tellus. Ut sed orci non justo eleifend luctus id a purus. Etiam pulvinar libero eget purus malesuada a blandit sapien bibendum. Integer laoreet accumsan pulvinar. Proin lobortis molestie odio sed mollis. Aliquam nec dui id erat molestie aliquam eu et risus. Suspendisse ipsum urna, iaculis eget ornare vitae, commodo a enim. Phasellus adipiscing diam eget ante dapibus dictum. Fusce quis massa a diam rhoncus varius eu quis orci. Integer ac urna nibh. Pellentesque ornare nisl sit amet elit euismod aliquet.
        </p>
        <p>
        Nulla egestas dolor sed mi pellentesque auctor. Aliquam dictum congue felis et tempus. Duis eu imperdiet diam. Morbi tristique ornare dapibus. Proin laoreet pellentesque enim. Proin a orci est. Aliquam quis sapien at risus vestibulum dignissim. Donec augue erat, egestas et ornare quis, pulvinar non felis. Donec tincidunt leo nec justo rhoncus varius. Phasellus odio nunc, porta et lobortis quis, luctus vel quam. Maecenas vehicula dictum vehicula. Integer mollis risus nisl. Donec feugiat congue urna, nec elementum orci rhoncus quis. Morbi sit amet elit odio, et aliquam tortor. Donec porttitor ullamcorper lacus, a commodo justo fringilla vel. Ut vel est ut arcu euismod pulvinar at vel ligula. Aliquam vestibulum turpis in mauris venenatis sit amet elementum mi blandit.
        </p>

        </div>
    </div>
       </div>
</div>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Anthony

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to the advice from Joseph below, I was able to fix the issue with the background pattern scrolling. The updated page can be seen here:

http://www2.hawaii.edu/~akinsey/sandbox/broken/index2.html

Now everything looks great when there is enough content to fill the page, but when there isn't the content div and bgwrap div won't extend to fill the page and turns out looking like this:

http://www2.hawaii.edu/~akinsey/sandbox/broken/

Thanks again for all your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

and to solve your other problem you could have the following HTML

```
<div id="bgwrap" style="width: 975px; height: 100%; position: fixed; left: 50%;
margin-left: -495px; background-image: url(&quot;../image/hawaiianpattern.gif&quot;); 
background-repeat: no-repeat;  background-position: right top; z-index: -1;"></div>
```

inserted directly before innerwrapper in wrapper... or anywhere else come to think of it.

**EDIT**

Oh and remove

```
background-image:url('../image/header1.png');
```

from #innerwrapper

Comment: Thank you, this fixed my issue with the background image to the right! I still seem to be having issues with getting the divs to extend to the bottom of the page. I've updated my question to reflect your fix. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

If i understood well you can fix one of the problems by removing this line

```
height:100%;
```

from #innerwrapper

If you change this, when you resize your background will be as is should be

for the background you may use background-attachment:fixed; 
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-attachment.asp

Comment: fixed won't work... wasted a good half hour trying that.  Problem is you can't have it dynamically adjust for window resize.

Comment: i wasted some time too trying to make it work with fixed...but I still think that this is the only CSS way for doing that

Comment: css? yes. html? no.  My solution above utilizes a fixed HTML element, and fixed is the way to go; it's just that it can't be done is css alone.  The problem is that once you make the bg fixed and set a position attribute to it, it will stick there.  If the left side of the viewport is outside the physical scope of the div, the bg just won't appear.  See here: http://jsfiddle.net/JuGcu/ EDIT: and yes I ripped that from w3schools

Comment: Hmm, I tried this and it didn't seem to do anything. Thanks for the advice! I've seemed to have resolved the issue with the background pattern thanks to the post by Joseph, but I'm still having issues getting the divs to extend to the bottom.